# String passed to function as object property name

Tags: javascript

In the function below, I want to pass two arguments. `instance` refers to an object, `prop` refers to an object property name.

```
door.x = 20; // door['x'] refers to the same
key(door, 'x');
function key(instance, prop) {
    Tween.get(instance, {override: true}).to({prop: -150}, instance[prop]);
}
```

Because I need to be able to refer to `door['x']` at one point (which is another way of writing `door.x`), `x` always need to be a string. However, the same `x` here needs to be used here as an object property name, but I can't have a string there, because the code would not work:

```
Tween.get(door, {override: true}).to({'x': -150}, door['x']); // does not work because a string has been passed as an object property name
```

What I really want is this:

```
Tween.get(door, {override: true}).to({x: -150}, door['x']); // works
```

So, my question is: is there some sort of method which allows me to 'unstring' a string? Or is there perhaps any other solution around this?

Comment: Then I'm misunderstanding what's going on then. `{x: -150}` works, but `{'x': 150}` does not. @AlexWayne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function key(instance, prop) {
    var obj = {}; 
    obj[prop] = -150; 
    Tween.get(instance, {override: true}).to(obj, instance[prop]);
}
```

Comment: That's a **very** clever way to do that.

Comment: Object literals may not have dynamic property names. So you have to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks @AlexWayne. Still learning :)

Comment: @AlexWayne What if I now want to use `instance` as a string too (but still keeping it as an object?) Like in `banana['instance']`? I cannot have an object between the brackets. Thanks :)

Comment: You cannot get a local variable by a string. But if was assigned to an object, you could fetch it by the property name on that object. `obj.myinstance = instance; var prop = 'myinstance'; obj[prop]`